# How to solve IntegrityError (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed) in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have this model system. The project contains entries. But when I try to delete Project I am getting this error. I am getting IntegrityError (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed) on deleting a project. How can I solve this error?

Here are my foreign key relations from models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
project_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
project_entry = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Entry(models.Model):
entry_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Comment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
reply = models.ForeignKey('Comment', null=True, blank=True,related_name="replies", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class EntryComment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(Entry, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
entryreply = models.ForeignKey('EntryComment', null=True, blank=True,related_name="entryreplies", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/lift/delete/



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 243, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()

The above exception (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 109, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 218, in post
    return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 213, in delete
    self.object.delete()
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 938, in delete
    return collector.delete()
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py", line 338, in delete
    sender=model, instance=obj, using=self.using
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 232, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 267, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 243, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\Projects\django_project\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 243, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /lift/delete/
Exception Value: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Delete view:

[image]

Comment: What does your `/lift/delete/` view look like? Also, Did you make sure to migrate after you added `models.CASCADE`?

Comment: I have updated the post for the delete view.  And Yes! I made migrations after making changes

Comment: have you applied the migration(s) with `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yes! I did migration

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you figure out yours?